# google maps tiles' center coordinates

Tags: maps, center, tiles

I am trying to create the tiles for google maps.
I use a third party handler which provides me map images. The handler needs as input the center's coordinates and a scale geographical value. I want to use this handler to create all the google tiles but i need the centers' of all tiles.

Is any way to calculate for a given zoom level the tiles' centers ?

Thank you in advanced!!

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question before, and figured it out myself later:

[Get center LatLng point of a custom tile in Google Maps API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25990570/get-center-latlng-point-of-a-custom-tile-in-google-maps-api-v3/25991835#25991835)

Wat is does if give you the div pixel center point, which you can convert to anything you want (in my case: LatLng).