# Get center LatLng point of a custom tile in Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've got a custom map type API I need to talk to.

I'd like to get the map images by using the 'tile' function of Google Maps. I've got the tiles setup like this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-overlay?hl=nl

The API to get the different tileimages requires me to have a center point for each of the tiles.

So how do I get/calculate the center LatLng point for each tile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I figured it out.

Here's what I did.

You have a tile coordinate for each tile (x,y) and zoom and a tile size.

So first we make a new Google MapsPoint to the center point of the tile:

```
var centerpoint = new google.maps.Point((coord.x * tileSize) + (tileSize / 2), ((coord.y + 1) * tileSize) + (tileSize / 2));
```

Then convert those x,y coordinates to LatLng (conversion functions and the math behind it can be found on http://www.maptiler.org)

So it was actually pretty simple...

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate it also directly:

```
n = 2 ^ zoom
lon_deg = xtile / n * 360.0 - 180.0
lat_rad = arctan(sinh(π * (1 - 2 * ytile / n)))
lat_deg = lat_rad * 180.0 / π
```

Source and code samples in various languages: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Tile_numbers_to_lon..2Flat.

Comment: I think this gives top-left corner lat-lng